# How to change the map view corresponding to the select box address in Magento?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

How to add Google map in CMS page and how to use this to search? when i list the address in select-box at the left side. when i select the address means the right side of map change to corresponding address. I am using Magento 1.7.0.2 . Can any one guide me.

Thanks in Advance,

Comment: You want someone to implement the whole thing for you?

Comment: No, i just ask how to do this or any references is their?

Answer (score 0):

you use extension for change view map that you use this extension in your e-commerce

http://www.growdevelopment.com/magento-extensions/store-locations-pro

i hope you your problem solve this extension than you fill happy

Comment: I need just a simple one, i don't need as complicate. I am use multiple store, so that i can search the address means that corresponding map shown that's all.